# Blog module with file attachment feature in magento 2

Tags: magento2.4, pdf, blog

Is there any extension available for blogs that allow attaching pdf, images, videos, and content specific to the blog in Magento 2.4?

Please suggest. free or paid anything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this one :

1. https://magefan.com/magento2-blog-extension
2. https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-better-blog/
3. https://amasty.com/blog-pro-for-magento-2.html
4. https://aheadworks.com/blog-extension-for-magento-2
5. https://mirasvit.com/magento-2-extensions/blog.html
6. https://www.magearray.com/blog-extension-for-magento-2.html

Comment: this does not have upload file functionality

Comment: Image you can found, but that is as blog image not attchment. and for attchment you need to customize those things.